# Storybook: how do I add controls for subcomponent?

Tags: storybook, storybook-addon, subcomponent

I building a FE library using Storybook, and I need to know how to use controls for subcomponent.
I even read [this article](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/stories-for-multiple-components#page-top) without success.
As you can see from my screenshow, the DrawerHeader doesn't show the control option, so that I can change its props.

Any clue?

I read the documentation without success